# MYSQL- How do I create individual tables for forum posts?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

For every forum post on my site, I'd like to create a MySQL table with the name of its id, in order to enable user commenting. The know-how will also come in handy when creating a table for each user registered, to enable friend tracking.

There are multiple posts across various sites about doing this. I figured that you need to prepare a statement and then append the $id variable to it- then execute. However, all the posts I've read about the topic were confusing and didn't work for me, so I'd like some advice. **I am trying to create a table using PHP.**

This is what the query should look like:

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE '$id' (...) ")
```

How do I prepare a statement? I don't really get it.

Or is there a better way to achieve my purpose than with prepared statements?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: This is not how you're supposed to use a **RELATIONAL** database...

Comment: There are much better ways to handle comments in a database than to have a separate table for each post. Why not just have a single `comments` table, and include a `post_id` that you can `SELECT` on?

Comment: Really a sperate table for each user and EVERY forum post! Creating a table is the least of your worries.

Comment: Dont -1 him for asking the question; he's learning. I did the same thing when I was learning MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create a table for each forum (or forum post, wasn't sure from your question). Simply create a table called comments and have a field in that table called 'forum_id'. When a user goes to create a comment on a forum or forum post, then have populate that field with the ID of the forum the user is commenting on. When pulling all comments back, just get all the comments for a particular forum based on the value of the forum_id field.

Comment: No problem. Work on learning more about creating relational databases, and when you get a good handle on that, you can read about prepared statements here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php   Prepared statements help with security and performance of SQL queries, but shouldn't necessarily cause a query to fail/succeed.